# Swift : TableView Cell data change with the Button Actions

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I create the Bus Ticket app. and not i'm setting my Dropping and Boarding point Screen. So I have a list of the data One is For Boarding point and Another is Dropping points in array Type. So I want to setUp As per The following image. When i Select the Boarding Button i want to show the list of the Boarding point and Similar for the Dropping Button.

[image]

So i just trying by Following Code But it's Not working for me.

```
 var arrBoardPoints = [SBDropPickPoint]()  
 var arrDropPoints = [SBDropPickPoint]()


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DroppingCell") as! DroppingCell
        if btnBoarding.isSelected == true {
            cell.lblDrop.text = arrBoardPoints[indexPath.row].title
            cell.lblAddress.text = arrBoardPoints[indexPath.row].address
            cell.lblTime.text = arrBoardPoints[indexPath.row].time
        } else btnDropping.isSelected == true {
            cell.lblDrop.text = arrDropPoints[indexPath.row].title
            cell.lblAddress.text = arrDropPoints[indexPath.row].address
            cell.lblTime.text = arrDropPoints[indexPath.row].time
        }
        return cell
    }
```

And I reload my tableView Data on the Both Dropping and Boarding Button Action.

Comment: Create segmentedController for boarding and dropping and whenever a user clicks on the particular field show that lists on cell and dropping, boarding lists UI is same or not?

Comment: yes both are same.

Comment: `btnBoarding.isSelected` or `btnDropping.isSelected`, is either one of them really true?

Comment: SBDropPickPoint is a model or library?

Comment: It's Model @AbhishekJadhav

Comment: yes one is true @Larme

Comment: Use UISegmentedControl and button is not right way to use for that functionality.

Comment: Use one array for **all** items and a second array for **filtered** items – Add `isBoarding` and `isDropping` properties to the data model – When a button is pressed filter all items by the properties and reload the table view similar to the search bar logic.

Comment: but how can i use the indexPath.row method in my segmented controll?

Comment: You can see the answer using segmented controller!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this step :-

1 -  Create UISegmentedController which has **two segment index one is Boarding and second is Dropping**

2 - Create the **`third array of your model`** in your controller

```
var arrPoints = [SBDropPickPoint]()
```

3 - **Add target method** of a **segmented controller** in **viewDidLoad method** and assign the first array to arrPoints and mention which segment selected to be first.

```
    arrPoints = arrBoardPoints
    segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    segmentedController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControllerValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

4 - Add code in the target method of a segmented controller which array list you want to display and then reload tableview.

```
@objc func segmentedControllerValueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            arrPoints = arrBoardPoints
        case 1:
            arrPoints = arrDropPoints
        default:
            print("Invalid")
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

5 - In your tableview datasource and delgate method use arrPoints model array to display list.

```
extension ControllerName: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrPoints.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DroppingCell") as! DroppingCell        
        cell.lblDrop.text = arrPoints[indexPath.row].title
        cell.lblAddress.text = arrPoints[indexPath.row].address
        cell.lblTime.text = arrPoints[indexPath.row].time

    return cell

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks. Working charm

Answer (score 0):

When you click on  btnBoarding then you need to do isSelected = false for dropping button. And ad visa versa if you clicked on btnDropping then  then you need to do btnBoarding = false also.